# Why is blocking access to the parent frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

There is a site: mydomain.com The site has a frame that loads information from mydomain.com/folder/index.html

This frame is an appeal by JS frame to the parent, ie, the main page, everything works fine, but after running the script:

https://github.com/DmitryKoterov/dklab_realplexor/blob/master/dklab_realplexor.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/dklab_realplexor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var realplexor = new Dklab_Realplexor('http://rpl.mydomain.com/', 'test_');
        realplexor.subscribe("Alpha", function(data) { alert("Alpha: " + data) });
        realplexor.execute();

    });
</script>
```

That creates even 1 frame, loading him about this information: https://github.com/DmitryKoterov/dklab_realplexor/blob/master/dklab_realplexor.html

When handling the frame 1 to the parent, for example: parent.myFunction (); I get the error: Error: Permission denied to access property "myFunction"

Why is that? How to access the functions of the parent element in this case?

Comment: i think your iframe is in a different domain. javascript can't access parent window data (and so the parent)

Comment: 1 iframe: mydomain.com/folder/index.html
2 iframe: rpl.mydomain.com

Once connected, the script that creates two iframe, I can not get access to the parent 1 iframe. I have all the above, read carefully